# Picker not working well after upgrade to iOS4

Tags: ios4

I have been re working the iPhone 3 dev book to see if it all works in iOS4.

All went well until I hit the Data Picker

Is anything changed there? I was able to get Date Picker to work but nothing after that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, nothing changed in UIPickerView itself for ios4.0.

You're problem is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to find updated documents for the iOS4 UIImagePickerController, Any Ideas? from what i can tell, Apple hasn't updated these yet.